# Using Spring Boot, how do I see debug info for Zuul?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud, netflix-zuul

I am trying to use Zuul within my Spring Boot project.

**application.properties**

```
server.context-path=/${spring.application.name}
zuul.routes.engine.path=/api/engine/**
zuul.routes.engine.url=${engine.url}
```

`GET` requests are working; however, Zuul is not forwarding my `POST` requests. I'm not seeing any of the debug output for either the `GET` or `POST` listed here: [How To Use](https://github.com/Netflix/zuul/wiki/How-To-Use).

How do I enable `DEBUG` logging mode for Zuul?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Set the property `zuul.debug.request=true`.

Comment: You can also use the `/trace` endpoint if you are using actuator.

Comment: This will flag me an error saying --> zuul.debug.request is unknown property

Comment: The IDE doesn't know about all netflix oss properties.

Answer (score 10):

Spencer's answer didn't work for me with current Zuul version (Spring Cloud Starter Zuul 1.4.6.RELEASE). What did work, instead, was adding the following logging property to application.yml

```
logging:
  level:
    org:
      springframework:
        cloud:
          netflix: trace
```

Answer (score 8):

To log request and responses in Spring application I successfully use property:

```
logging:
  level:
    org:
      apache:
        http:
          wire: debug
```

Answer (score 4):

You need two things:

1. Add `zuul.include-debug-header: true` to your `application.yml` file.
2. Append `debug=true` to your request, e.g. `http://localhost:8080/api/user/1?debug=true`

This way you will receive debug data in `X-Zuul-Debug-Header` in the response

Comment: This works however I find the debugging information quite hard to understand

Answer (score 1):

We are using

```
spring-boot-2.3.3.RELEASE 
spring-cloud-netflix-zuul-2.2.4.RELEASE
zuul-core-1.3.1
```

I added

```
zuul:
  include-debug-header: true
  debug.request: true
  debugFilters.disabled: false
```

to my application.yml file.

I added

```
com.netflix.zuul.context.Debug.setDebugRequest(true);
com.netflix.zuul.context.Debug.setDebugRequestHeadersOnly(true);
com.netflix.zuul.context.Debug.setDebugRouting(true);
```

to one of my filter's doFilter() method:

```
public void doFilter(ServletRequest servletRequest, ServletResponse servletResponse, FilterChain filterChain)
```

Then the response of every request contained a new header X-Zuul-Debug-Header with the list of zuul filters that ran to process that request.